# Is $\mathrm{binomial}(n, p)$ family both full and curved for $n$ fixed?

Tags: binomial-distribution, exponential-family

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer. The binomial$(n, p)$ family is given by
$$f(x|p)=\tbinom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\tag{1}.$$
We may rewrite (1) as
$$f(x|p)=\tbinom{n}{x}(1-p)^n\exp\left[x\log\frac{p}{1-p}\right]$$
and say binomial$(n, p)$ is a full exponential family. However one could rearrange (1) as
$$f(x|p)=\tbinom{n}{x}\exp \left[x\log p+(n-x)\log(1-p)\right].$$
Now it becomes a curved exponential family as $n$ is fixed.

I'm a beginner of statistics. I do know there is an example (ex: normal family) that the distribution is full but curved as parameters satisfy some specific relationship. Is it right that binomial$(n, p)$ family is both full and curved?

[Reference]

1. Statistical Inference, George Casella and Roger L. Berger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Casella & Berger](https://amzn.to/34VUdE3), [p.137-38](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/383960/14893):

[image: ![enter image description here]

When $n$ is given, (1) is an exponential family. It is full as the parameter space $(0,1)$ is the largest possible. In the sense that
$$\log p - \log (1-p)$$
ranges $(-\infty,+\infty)$ when $p\in(0,1)$. Rewriting it as
$$ f(x|p)=\tbinom{n}{x}\exp \left[x\log p+(n-x)\log(1-p)\right]\tag{2}$$
is seemingly increasing the dimension of the natural statistic and hence gives the impression of a curved exponential family, but this is only an impression since $x$ and $(n-x)$ are linearly dependent:
$$ x+(n-x)=n$$
The representation (2) is thus not minimal. In other words, one can rewrite (2) as
$$\exp \left[x\log p+(n-x)\log(1-p)\right]=\exp \left[x\{\log p-\log(1-p)\}\underbrace{+n\log(1-p)}_{\substack{\text{normalising}\\ \text{constant}}}\right]$$
and deduce there is a dimension-one sufficient statistic.